# Javascript enable input boxes on checked box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want when I check my checkbox enable input box, I made that code like this:

```
function free(){
    var free_var = document.getElementById('free_id');
    var delivery_price = document.getElementById('delivery_price');

    if(free_var.checked){
        delivery_price.disabled=true;
    }else{
        delivery_price.disabled=false;
    }                       
}
```

but my problem is that i have more checkboxes and inputs like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="47.5" class="c26"/> 37.5  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Količina" style="width:60px;" class="c26_i" disabled/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="48" class="c27"/> 41  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Količina" style="width:60px;" class="c27_i" disabled/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="48.5" class="c28"/> 44  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Količina" style="width:60px;" class="c28_i" disabled/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="49" class="c29"/> 47  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Količina" style="width:60px;" class="c29_i" disabled/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="site[]" value="49.5" class="c30"/> 50  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Količina" style="width:60px;" class="c30_i" disabled/>
```

This is code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b02e392v/

Thanks

Comment: You need to call your `free()` function `onchange` of your checkbox. Also you aren't using the id's u have in your `free()` function...

Comment: So what is it that you want the code to do differently?  Also, how are 'free_id' and 'delivery_price' relevant?  They're nowhere in the HTML.  Also, can you add _all_ parts needed to demonstrate the problem, to your jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, sorry i didn't mention that my js code is from another part of my code, so id's aren't problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    var status = this.checked;
    $(this).next().attr("disabled", !status);
});
```

On change of `checkbox` fetch whether it is checked or not, accordingly set the disabled attribute of the `input` next to the clicked checkbox.

[Play it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/b02e392v/4/)

Comment: Very nice solution +1

Comment: Glad it worked, consider voting it up and marking it correct answer.

Comment: Very nice and simple solution. Less lines of code returning expected results. Kudos.. @void